# A rectangle has diagonals $d$ and the acute angle between the diagonals $\alpha$, express...

Tags: geometry

**Problem:** A rectangle has diagonals with length $d$ and the acute angle between the diagonals $\alpha$. Let $\cos{\alpha}=p,$ express the length short side in terms of $p$ and $d.$

**Attempt:** Drawing the problem, it gives us an Isosceles with sides $d/2, \ d/2$ and let's denote the sought short side with $s:$

[image]

The law of cosines gives: $$s^2=\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2-2\cdot\frac{d}{2}\cdot\frac{d}{2}\cdot\cos{\alpha}=\frac{d^2}{2}(1-p).$$

So, $$s=\sqrt{\frac{d^2}{2}(1-p)}=\frac{d\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p}}{2}.$$

I cant figure out why the answer in the book is $$s=\frac{d\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-p^2}}{2},$$

why $p^2$ instead of just $p$ ?

Comment: Probably a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in the book is wrong. Your answer is correct.